# SELECT * FROM issue

Tags: php, mysql

I have been searching around for about 30 minutes, and I just can't find the issue here...

```
if($middle == 'garage'){
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM character WHERE username = '$username'") or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $return['middle'] = $row['username'];
}
```

For some reason this is returning

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'character WHERE username = 'Alcapwn'' at line 1

I have tried so many things, other SELECT * FROM query's are working fine, it's just this one. The table and row containing it is there. If I switch

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM character WHERE username = '$username'") or die(mysql_error());
```

to

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'") or die(mysql_error());
```

the second one will work, but not the first.

Comment: It's an old comment, but as a beginner it's critical to learn early on so you don't have to change an entire application in the future. Use PDO or mysqli_* functions instead of the mysql_* stack. See http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`character` is a [reserved mysql word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html), so you have to enclose it in backticks

```
FROM `character` ...
```

Comment: @Alcapwn: it's not possible. Show the new code and the **exact** error message

Comment: I did however look into the fact that it's a reserved word, and switched the table name. It works fine now. Thank you very much.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have enough rep to vote it up. :( Once again, thank you very much. My teacher decided to "glance" over a lot of things I guess.

Comment: @Alcapwn: you may check an answer even with 1 rep

Answer (score 0):

It seems that **character** is a MySQL Reserved Keyword, which means you cannot use it as table name.

Answer (score 0):

"Character" is a reserved word in MySQL.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html